# How do I add an active class to a list of items when an item is clicked on in Ember?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a list of items in an Ember template that looks like:

```
<ul>
  {{#each color in colors}}
    <li {{action 'changeColor' color}}>{{color.hexValue}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

In my controller, I have the following:

```
Ember.Controller.extend({
  selectedColor: null,
  colors: [
    { 'name': 'black', 'hexValue': '000000' },
    { 'name': 'white', 'hexValue': 'ffffff' },
    { 'name': 'red', 'hexValue': 'ff0000' }
  ],

  actions: {
    changeColor: function(newColor) {
      this.set('selectedColor', 'newColor');
    }
  });
```

When a color is clicked, I'd like to add an active class to the `<li>` that corresponds to the clicked item. `selectedColor` can also be set to a default color (instead of null), and I'd like the `<li>` that has the corresponding color to have the active class on page load.

The other SO questions I've seen have been about how to set the parent element for a `{{link-to}}` to active (mostly for Twitter Bootstrap's nav), but in this case I'm not using `{{link-to}}` and I'm not doing a route change.

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your action doesn't work and will alwas set the select color to the string 'newColor'.

Anyway, you can use a computed Property `showColors`, that includes the class to be rendered in the template, like this:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  selectedColor: null,
  colors: [
    { 'name': 'black', 'hexValue': '000000' },
    { 'name': 'white', 'hexValue': 'ffffff' },
    { 'name': 'red', 'hexValue': 'ff0000' }
  ],

  showColors: Ember.computed('colors', 'selectedColor', function(){
    var that = this;
    return this.get('colors').map(function(color){
      return {
        'name': color.name,
        'hexValue': color.hexValue,
        'class': (color.hexValue == that.get('selectedColor.hexValue')) ? 'active' : ''
      };
    });
 }),

  actions: {
    changeColor: function(newColor) {
      this.set('selectedColor', newColor);
    }
  }
});
```

([Working example](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/reweteliho/1/edit?html,css,js,output))

Comment: Thanks, this is what I ended up using. I hope Ember adds this as a first-class feature sometime, since it's a pretty common feature (select an item in a list by adding a class to the clicked item).